# Can I setup a subdomain to be forwarded to a specific port?

Tags: wamp, port, windows-server-2012

For example, I have sonarr setup on http://my-domain-name.com:38081. Can I setup a subdomain like sonarr.my-domain-name.com or my-domain-name.com/sonarr? I just hate having to remember what port if I'm accessing this remotely.

I'm using WAMP on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Look at [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for apache.

```
ProxyPass /sonarr http://my-domain-name.com:38081/
```